# Getting -- TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toSource'

Tags: node.js

Command Executed :

```
  arguments.toSource();
```

I am getting the below error when I am accessing the arguments in any function to display the arguments.

```
  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toSource'
```

Is arguments is array or not ?

Comment: the default object which is accessible in any nodejs function, which is used to access the arguments of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` is array-like, but not a full JavaScript `Array`.

It has no `toSource` method; see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments, actually when I debugging nodejs functions also it is showing the arguments as Object not array. Thanks